# NoneType is not iterable when using dict.get() method

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have input JSON that looks like this:

```
{"employees": [{"foo": "bar"}]}
```

At times employees can be empty, or not exist. Rather than checking for the existence of the employees key within the dict, and ensuring it is not empty, like so:

```
if employees in data and data["employees"]:
```

I am using the `.get()` method to iterate, setting an empty list as default:

```
for i in data.get("employees", []):
```

However, if my input data looks like this:

```
{"employees": None}
```

Then I get the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. My assumption here is that the `dict.get()` method only sets the default if it is not defined, and having a NoneType value means that it is defined.

Is there a way to make the `dict.get()` method set the default if the key exists but the value is None?

Comment: you can solve this by not  having a None as default. The get method find a None type which is not iterable. An alternative would be a try except clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My assumption here is that the dict.get() method only sets the default if it is not defined, and having a NoneType value means that it is defined.

`dict.get(key[,default=None))` doesn't "set" anything. It returns the value for the given key if this key is in the dict, else the `default` value.

> Is there a way to make the dict.get() method set the default if the key exists but the value is None?

Nope, you have to do it manually - but it's not that complicated, and, in you case, not even necessary:

```
  employees = data.get("employees") or []
```

NB: you *could* of course define your own dict subclass, redefine `get` to work as you want and tell the `json` unserializer to use your own subclass instead of `dict` but for such a use case this would be a bit overkill... and certainly much more complicated for no good reason.

Comment: I went with `for item in data.get("employees") or []` and that worked perfectly. Thanks!